# Fetch the generated database name and substitute using bash

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

I have a terraform script which installs wordpress automatically. The terraform script runs fine but the issue is with the user data. I want to replace the `localhost` entry in the `wp-config.php` file to the rds db instance id. I am passing the file as the user data. Here is the code which i am using.

```
rds=$(aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address" --output text)
cd /var/www/html
cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php
sed -i "s/database_name_here/WPTestDevRDS/g" wp-config.php
sed -i "s/username_here/admin/g" wp-config.php
sed -i "s/password_here/Adminhere1234/g" wp-config.php
sed -i "s/localhost/$rds/g" wp-config.php
```

The user data is getting executed but the issue is i am not able to replace the value of localhost to the value of`$rds`. The localhost entry is removed but the value of the variable $rds is not getting assigned. I  have also tried using  `${rds}` in sed but it didnt work.Any help in this situation is appreciated.

I am expecting the value of `$rds` instead of localhost. A sample look of the wp-config.php file

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'WPTestDevRDS' );^M
^M
/** Database username */^M
define( 'DB_USER', 'admin' );^M
^M
/** Database password */^M
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'Adminhere1234' );^M
^M
/** Database hostname */^M
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );^M      //i need to replace localhost with the value of $rds
```

Comment: Could it be that `rds` happens to be the string _localhost_? Also, in case that the DB_HOST definition happens to be the last line in the config file: Did you check that the line has a line feed at the end?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Why do you have so many carriage return characters in your config file? You are on Linux, after all. Can PHP handle them?

Comment: @user1934428 it seems like the value of $rds is not able to store as variable when its given as user data

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your sentence. What does it mean that _a value is not able to store as variable_? A "value" does not have any ability, and certainly not the ability to store something. In your code, the variable `rds` contains the output of the `aws` command, and you could simply do a `echo "$rds"` or better a `xxd <<<$rds` to verify what is stored  in this variable.

Comment: @user1934428 yes exactly.. am able to echo the value out but the problem is am not able to replace the value of localhost in the wp-config.php file to the aws value returned.

Comment: Can't be. The `sed` command looks right. Did you check the line endings, as I told you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the variable has the expected value or at least it's not empty

```
rds=$(aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address" --output text)
if [[ -z "$rds" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR" >&2
    exit 1
fi
...
```

Comment: when i run the command `aws rds --region us-east-2 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address" --output text` it gives me the result but the issue is the value is not fetching when passed on user data.